Can a shower be a Mikvah if so how?
I was told that a shower can be used if a Mikvah is not available.  Is this so or only in certain cases?

It is definitely not applicable in all cases. As a general rule, it only works in times you don't really need a mikva: then a fake mikva can work for a "fake" requirement. New vessels, women after their periods, and anyone going up to the temple mount definitely really need a real mikva and all opinions agree a shower would do absolutely nothing.
